# Call initialize in hybris from Java

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

I want to initialize a demo hybris system every 2 days. How can I call the initialize from a Cronjob?

I already searched for it but didn't found any solutions

Comment: write one shell script and call `ant initialize`

Answer (score 1):

You can initialize your system through ant target `ant initialize`. Configure a shell script in crontab like...

**hybrisServer.sh**

```
cd /opt/app/hybris/bin/platform/
./hybrisserver.sh stop
. ./setantenv.sh
ant initialize
./hybrisserver.sh start
```

**crontab -e**

```
0      24     */2       *       *  hybrisServer.sh
```